# Unit Testing Isolated Model Azure Durable Function Orchestrator in .Net 8

Tags: unit-testing, azure-durable-functions, azure-functions-isolated, dotnet-isolated

The documentation for Durable Function Testing only talks about the in-proc model - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-unit-testing

I have a timer-triggered orchestrator as below -

```
 public class Orchestrator
 {
     private IMapper mapper;
     private IRepository repository;

     public Orchestrator(IMapper mapper, IRepository repository)
     {
         this.mapper = mapper;
         this.repository = repository;
     }

     [Function(nameof(Orchestrator))]
     public async Task RunOrchestrator(
         [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
     {
         ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(ConnectorOrchestrator));

         IEnumerable<Result> results;

         try
         {
             results = await repository.GetAllResultsAsync();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             logger.LogError(ex, $"Error getting results.");
             throw;
         }

         foreach (var result in results)
         {
             try
             {
                 _ = context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(Activity), result);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 logger.LogError(ex, $"Error calling activity.");
                 throw;
             }
         }
     }

     [Function(nameof(Activity))]
     public void ProcessAlerts([ActivityTrigger] Result result, FunctionContext executionContext)
     {

         logger.LogInformation($"Activity started.");

         logger.LogInformation($"Activity completed");
     }

     [Function("Orchestrator_ScheduledStart")]
     public async Task ScheduledStart(
         [TimerTrigger("* */15 * * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo,
         [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
         FunctionContext executionContext)
     {
         ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Orchestrator_ScheduledStart");

         string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
             nameof(ConnectorOrchestrator));

         logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);
     }
 }
```

In the below test, I get an error that DurableTaskClient cannot be mocked -

```
public OrchestratorTests()
{
    mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
    repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
    durableClient = new Mock<DurableTaskClient>();
    connectorOrchestrator = new ConnectorOrchestrator(mapper.Object, repository.Object);
}

[Fact]
public async Task ScheduledStart_ShouldTriggerOrchestrator()
{
    TimerInfo timerInfo = new TimerInfo();
    Mock<FunctionContext> functionContext = new Mock<FunctionContext>();
    await connectorOrchestrator.ScheduledStart(timerInfo, durableClient.Object, functionContext.Object);

    durableClient.Verify(client => client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(Orchestrator), null, null, default), Times.Once);
}
```

Is there any way to test isolated durable orchestrators today?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with a bit of boilerplate code and some fakes. What I personally did is :

- Create a FakeDurableTaskClient class implementing DurableTaskClient.
- Instantiate a Mock and pass its Object field (here of type FakeDurableTaskClient) to the method I want to test.
  My fake class looks as follows :

```
public class FakeDurableTaskClient : DurableTaskClient
{
    public FakeDurableTaskClient() : base("fake")
    {
    }

    public override Task<string> ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(TaskName orchestratorName, object input = null, StartOrchestrationOptions options = null,
        CancellationToken cancellation = new())
    {
        return Task.FromResult(options?.InstanceId ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }

    public override Task RaiseEventAsync(string instanceId, string eventName, object eventPayload = null, CancellationToken cancellation = new())
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override Task<OrchestrationMetadata> WaitForInstanceStartAsync(string instanceId, bool getInputsAndOutputs = false,
        CancellationToken cancellation = new())
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new OrchestrationMetadata(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), instanceId));
    }

    public override Task<OrchestrationMetadata> WaitForInstanceCompletionAsync(string instanceId, bool getInputsAndOutputs = false,
        CancellationToken cancellation = new())
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new OrchestrationMetadata(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), instanceId));
    }

    public override Task TerminateInstanceAsync(string instanceId, object output = null, CancellationToken cancellation = new())
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override Task SuspendInstanceAsync(string instanceId, string reason = null, CancellationToken cancellation = new())
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override Task ResumeInstanceAsync(string instanceId, string reason = null, CancellationToken cancellation = new())
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override Task<OrchestrationMetadata> GetInstancesAsync(string instanceId, bool getInputsAndOutputs = false,
        CancellationToken cancellation = new())
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new OrchestrationMetadata(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), instanceId));
    }

    public override AsyncPageable<OrchestrationMetadata> GetAllInstancesAsync(OrchestrationQuery filter = null)
    {
        return new FakeOrchestrationMetadataAsyncPageable();
    }

    public override Task<PurgeResult> PurgeInstanceAsync(string instanceId, CancellationToken cancellation = new())
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new PurgeResult(1));
    }

    public override Task<PurgeResult> PurgeAllInstancesAsync(PurgeInstancesFilter filter, CancellationToken cancellation = new())
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new PurgeResult(Random.Shared.Next()));
    }

    public override ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I also had to create a fake of AsyncPageable :

```
internal class FakeOrchestrationMetadataAsyncPageable : AsyncPageable<OrchestrationMetadata>
{
    public override IAsyncEnumerable<Page<OrchestrationMetadata>> AsPages(string continuationToken = null, int? pageSizeHint = null)
    {
        return AsyncEnumerable.Empty<Page<OrchestrationMetadata>>();
    }
}
```

If I take your example, the following should work using those fakes :

```
public OrchestratorTests()
{
    mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
    repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
    durableClient = new Mock<FakeDurableTaskClient>();
    connectorOrchestrator = new ConnectorOrchestrator(mapper.Object, repository.Object);
}

[Fact]
public async Task ScheduledStart_ShouldTriggerOrchestrator()
{
    TimerInfo timerInfo = new TimerInfo();
    Mock<FunctionContext> functionContext = new Mock<FunctionContext>();
    await connectorOrchestrator.ScheduledStart(timerInfo, durableClient.Object, functionContext.Object);

    durableClient.Verify(client => client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(Orchestrator), null, null, default), Times.Once);
}
```

I cannot guarantee it works with every use-case (I didn't test it with the Entities so far) and it doesn't really feel natural. I would appreciate a more comfortable out-of-the-box solution. But until now, I don't have any better idea.

Comment: Thank you, this was so helpful! In a similar way, I'm trying to mock the TaskOrchestrationContext. In this, I'm unable to ovverride or setup 'CreateReplaySafeLogger' because it's not abstract. Every time the code reaches this point, it throws a null reference exception. I can see that it is internally using ILoggerFactory, but does that mean I mean I need to mock ILoggerFactory too, and then override the LoggerFactory method in FakeTaskOrchestrationContext?