Durable Functions Unit Test - SystemNotSupported Exception
I am attempting to write unit tests for an Activity function in a Durable Function Orchestration. I am using the template created by VS 2022. When I try to mock an ILogger I am getting an SystemNotSupported exception.
The function I am trying to test:
        [Function(nameof(MyFunction))]
        public static string MyFunction([ActivityTrigger] MyParameters input, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("MyFunction");
            logger.LogInformation("Testing MyFunction...);

            return "It worked!";
        }

My test where I try to mock the logger being passed in:
        [Test]
        public async Task MyFunction_ValidParameters_ReturnsValidString()
        {
            // Arrange
            Mock<FunctionContext> funcContextMock = new Mock<FunctionContext>();
            funcContextMock.Setup(s => s.GetLogger(It.IsAny<string>()))
                           .Returns(Mock.Of<ILogger>);

            // Act
            string blobName = await MyClass.MyFunction(input, funcContextMock.Object);

            // Assert
            Assert.That(blobName, Is.Not.Null);
            Assert.That(blobName, Is.Not.Empty);
            Assert.That(blobName, Does.StartWith(input.ExtractName));
        }

It is throwing when I try to setup the GetLogger().
I understand the exception, but I have not found a way to intercept the logger being used in the activity function. How can that be done?
As a side question, I see that others encourage dependency injection for unit testing  durable functions. Is there a way to modify my code to do that? The Microsoft help page on unit tests, the methods have very different signatures than what is currently generated by VS2022. What is the difference?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-unit-testing

Document is for Inprocess Model, which do not use Getlogger method. Your code in Isolated model. I would suggest use In-Process method or for Isloated model check this work around given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77985951/unit-testing-isolated-model-azure-durable-function-orchestrator-in-net-8

Everything I have read is that the isolated model should be preferred. But naturally all of the Microsoft examples are for In-process.

As I mentioned in comment.
The Document which you are following is for In-process model which do not uses CreateReplaySafeLogger, GetLogger method.
I also created a Durable function in Isolated model and tried to test using xUnit and MOQ,  I was also getting same error but also there is message saying these methods may not be used in  setup/ verification expression.


Whereas, there is no CreateReplaySafeLogger, GetLogger method in In-process.
I would suggest you to use In-process model for testing.
I don't think is is possible direct way in Isolated model.
For workaround I would suggest check this SO link
